# Do I apportion XP to NPC allies?

Tags: dnd-4e, npc

I'm running a D&D 4e duet game.  Recently, the PC picked up a couple temporary NPC companions.  Now they have completed their first encounter together, and I'm not sure what to do about experience.  If the encounter is 600xp, for example, and there is one PC and two NPCs, do I just give 200xp to each?  For the record, the two NPCs were very much a part of successfully completing the encounter(as opposed to bystanders).

The reason I'm unsure is that I feel like I'm punishing the PC for inviting the two NPCs, who I introduced, to join him.  Had I not introduced the NPCs, the PC could still have taken on the encounter and, if successful, gotten all the XP for himself.

Even if I had made the encounter easier for the PC by himself, which is likely, all of 400xp is more than a third of 600xp.

It would be a shame if I inadvertently trained my PC to avoid NPC allies because, in a way, it costs him XP (not that he's some kind of XP miser).

I saw [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-should-i-budget-for-ally-third-party-npcs-in-4e-combats), but it's only got the one answer, most of which was focused away from what I'm asking.  It'd be nice to get a few more bits of insight.  Are there options other than "Yes, split it evenly," and "No, give it all to the PC?"  Or is one or the other of those the most accepted method?

Thanks!

Comment: Wanting more answers isn't a reason to ask a new question - they really are the same.  You can edit, comment on, answer, or bounty the old one to get it more attention.

Comment: With due respect, they're really different. That question deals primarily with the issue of NPCs that may or may not turn out to be allies of the PCs and what to do depending on how an encounter unfolds with those NPCs. I'm dealing with NPCs I introduced as allies out of combat. I also feel like the "duet" aspect of my question separates it from the other question.  Or maybe it doesn't.  Regardless, I'm not sure commenting on, or answering, a question with a question is a good idea. I would fully expect someone to comment on my comment, say that it is unrelated, and please make a new question.

Comment: no, they ask first about the same situation (I don't see how duet has anything to do with it) and then add on some additional complicating rider questions.  Feel free and comment or bounty that one though.

Comment: And the answer to the same situation is "You are correct."  Unfortunately, the question said, "I can see two options."  Which option is correct?  Yes isn't a helpful answer to a multiple choice question.

Comment: Quite, so try to draw more answers. I'm sorry, we consider all Q&As to be "evergreen" and duplicates are never appropriate, there's plenty of ways to light up an existing one.  I've edited and commented on that one already, which will pull it to the front page for most people.

Comment: Ha!  I see you have already posed it.  I don't have a lot of experience with D&D.  To me, a duet game is very different, but I guess it's not. I would also hate to turn that person's question away from its intended purpose.  I can say, "Which option?" Then, "Why?" Then, "Are there other options?" And suddenly that question is about my question, instead of about theirs.  Advice?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13218/discussion-between-mxyzplk-and-lechlerfan)